# Understanding how password less key based login works between two hosts

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to enable password less key based login between two hosts, however I am unable to wrap my head around how this actually works under the hood. So looking some helm to get my concepts cleared.

I am on `host1` logged in as `user1`. Now from here I plan to remotely execute a command on `host2`.

```
[user1@host1 ~]$ ssh user2@host2 pwd
The authenticity of host 'host2 (***.***.***.*)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:******************.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'host2,***.***.***.*' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
user2@host2's password:
```

What am I confused here, to enable password less login for `user2@host2`.

1. Do I need to add `user1`'s public key [`~/.ssh/id_*.pub`] generated
   on `host1` to the authorized keys on `host2` under `user1`'s `ssh/authorized_keys`, since on `host1` I am logged in with `user1`?, Or
2. Do I need to add `user2`'s public key [`~/.ssh/id_*.pub`]
   generated on `host1` to authorized keys on `host2` under `user1`'s `ssh/authorized_keys'`? Or
3. Do I need to add `user2`'s public key [`~/.ssh/id_*.pub`]
   generated on `host1` to authorized keys on `host2` under `user2`'s `ssh/authorized_keys'`? Or

Sorry if this is too basic or confusing question, I tried my best to explain what I am confused about. TIA!

Comment: You are in the source pc as source user. You want to connect the destination pc as destination user. [sourcehost@sourceuser] : ssh destinationuser@destinationpc
Your key come from sourceuser .ssh/id_rsa and the destination pc check it. => if the sourceuser public key is in the destination user's authorized_keys, you can log in.

Comment: @K-att- so i can login and execute as `destinationuser` without using any of its password or keys? In other words, how i can i use `sourceuser`'s credentials to work as `destinationuser`

Comment: With your key. Your public pair of your key need to include into the destinationuser authoried_keys file. The destinationuser allow the login for the owner of the secret key (sourceuser). In the destination pc you use the destination user's credentials.

Comment: Instead of random usernames, assume persons. `bob@a` wants to ssh to `b`, so he first has to add his public key to `b`s `authorized_keys` file by providing a password (or another already setup private key), proving its him. Then he can use his new key.

Comment: Just change `ssh` to `ssh-copy-id`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SSH Public Key (password less) login, then this is my understanding of what's going on.

1. You generate a private key / public key pair for use with SSH.  E.g. using the ssh-keygen command utility.
2. You put the private key into a file on the source PC, accessible only to the user that will initiate the ssh connection from the source PC.  In your case, you put this into a file like ~user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa on host1.
3. You put the public key into a file on the destination PC, accessible to the user that you wish to become on the destination PC.  In your case, you put this into a file like ~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys on host2.

Note: The only connection between the key pair and a user is the fact that you place the keys in that user's ~/.ssh directory.  The keys themselves don't have any functional connection to a specific user (although, in many cases, the comment at the end of a line in the authorized_keys / id_*.pub files may give you the impression that a key is tied to a specific user).

Note: The key pair can be generated anywhere there is some utility to do so.  The pair does not have to be generated on either the source or destination hosts.

Note: Assumes password less authentication is enabled, which is likely the default.